# directive isolate scope data undefined in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller, isolate-scope, angularjs-view

I have been writing down a module for image gallery, I have got a issue with it, my isolate scope is becoming undefined and does not change its state. I cannot understand the reason for it.

I have attached a *plnkr* -
http://plnkr.co/edit/3SJF4AwTeL2osvdEOlmc?p=preview

***gallery.directive.js***

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    function GalleryDirective () {

        var directive = {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: './gallery.html',
            controller: 'GalleryController',
            controllerAs: 'galc',
            bindToController: true,
            scope: {
                'gallerydata': '='
            }
        };

        return directive;

        ////////////////////////////

        function link (scope, element, attribute) {

        }
    }

    GalleryDirective.$inject = [];

    angular.module("gallery").directive("gallery", GalleryDirective);

})();
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Now I have added entirety of I was using inorder to curb the confusion of global variable - please see code here http://plnkr.co/edit/3SJF4AwTeL2osvdEOlmc?p=preview

I have been using it with store directive  - where gallery directive consumes data from it.

**Question** - I accept the images are appearing perfectly, but in my console I am not able to see `Array[3]`, instead an `undefined` is printed. Check the line below *Gallery Controller* where I try printing `vm.gallerydata` from the console.

**EDIT**

Undefined Image:
[image]

I am able to see the images appearing in the view, but controller prints `vm.gallerydata` to be undefined.

Comment: How can we help you if you do not provide complete code?

Comment: @Peterson Click the plnkr link

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in the data as a global variable, that won't work.

`gallery_data` wasn't defined on any controller nor was the directive being used in a controller context. I've added a basic controller where the data gets instantiated, I've also added the controller on the body.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('gallery').controller('MyCtrl', function() {
          var vm = this;
          vm.gallery_data = [
                    {
                        "title": "Image 1",
                        "imageurl": "http://placehold.it/150x100"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Image 1",
                        "imageurl": "http://placehold.it/150x100"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Image 1",
                        "imageurl": "http://placehold.it/150x100"
                    }
                ]
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
        <gallery gallerydata="ctrl.gallery_data"></gallery>
    </body>
```

Here is [an updated working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/i4sK4WydR84nSVW9WGNb?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/XnoUXXUOmYHPaInaQN5l?p=preview

Angular template does not use the javascript context in his templates.

You have to bind your data with either the `$rootScope` or with a `$scope` of a controller.

Here is the releveant plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/XnoUXXUOmYHPaInaQN5l?p=preview

And the relevant code :

```
//added the definition of the controller in the module
angular.module('gallery', []).controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope. gallery_data = [
                {
                    "title": "Image 1",
                    "imageurl": "http://placehold.it/150x100"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Image 1",
                    "imageurl": "http://placehold.it/150x100"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Image 1",
                    "imageurl": "http://placehold.it/150x100"
                }
            ];

}]);
// i added the ng-controller
<body ng-controller="mainController">
    <gallery gallerydata="gallery_data"></gallery>
</body>
```

EDIT : fix the $watch to :

```
    $scope.$watch(function(){
      return vm.gallerydata;

    }, function (current, original) {
        $log.info('vm.gallerydata was %s', original);
        $log.info('vm.gallerydata is now %s', current);
    });
```

Comment: i looked into it, the Array[3] print successfully in my broswer (chrome) what browser do you use ?

Comment: Not always, It is sporadically giving array[3], try stopping and rerunning.

Comment: i guess you meant the `$watch` ? It's because how you write it it can't work, i edit my post to add the fix.

Comment: hey..sorry...watch has nothing to do with this...my question is simple I am attempting to print incoming array of object received by my isolate scope into my controller, it is giving away `undefined`, but did you see the images are appearing good and well...How did this happen?

Comment: I don't see any undefined happened. I see only `vm.gallerydata is now undefined` with your code, which has to do with $watch because the relevant code is in the $watch. I don't have any undefined outside of the $watch. Now if you don't use static data but use data loaded from the server for your real application, it's normal that you'd have an undefined when the directive's controller is executed.

Comment: I have edited the question by adding image of what I am seeing. There is a code in ``gallery.controller.js` to print the value `$log.log(vm.gallerydata);` which is giving away undefined and it is not inside the watch function.

Comment: I am not getting the second part. I am loading data by deferring a promise, it shouldn't be printing an undefined at any cost. Please explain.

Comment: Yes it should, that's the price of asynchronous loading. Promise resolve execution are done on the next loop in javascript, so after all the directives/controller get executed. If you want to know when your data will be first not undefined, use $watch ad check the newValue. If you don't like undefined, you can initialize the gallery_data to []. So you'll have an empty array while your data are loading instead of undefined value.

Comment: Oh..I am not aware of it..But, how exactly I make it reflect?

Comment: What do you mean ?